Exploration EVA by donning a dust protection suit over a pressure suit
It seems to me that a pressure suit for the Moon or Mars would be a lot easier to design if astronauts were simply required to don a dust protection suit over the pressure suit before going outside. Is there any evidence that this idea has been evaluated by NASA or any other space agency? If it was, were any findings published?


Kinda https://www.mines.edu/capstoneseniordesign/project/lunar-dust-mitigation-eva-suit-coverings/

@OrganicMarble - that seems like it could be an answer. Even though the question was about a solution that involves a full suit covering, that may not be a hard constraint since the CSM engineering students are exploring a similar solution of covering the vulnerable areas of the spacesuit.

Nice concept. There is research into materials that shed dust using electrical charge. This "onesy" design begs the opposite: material which could be charged to hold onto the dust. This would minimize dust contamination when doffing the suit. Maybe Swiffer could be sub-contracted.

I think the problem you're going to run into is that a relatively loose over-suit is likely to bind around joints or obscure important ports, readouts, etc. I think the project.  Disposable or washable coverings for specific areas is more likely to be a useful plan, I would think.

It would be nice if you could 3d print and recycle them (like replicators in StarTrek), otherwise there may be sizing or limited supply issues. Also they don’t look super cool or futuristic.
